# How do I condense multiple jQuery functions into one concise function?

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hope someone can help! I'm a jQuery/JS novice. Is there an easy way to condense multiple functions into one. I'm using jQuery to expand and collapse some hidden divs. I've got it working fine with the code below, but there could be 50+ (not just 4) and I assume there would be a way to condense them into a small chunk of code in the name of optimization. Any help would be very gratefully received. Here's the JS...

```
$('#toggle1').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
    });

    $('#toggle2').click(function() {
    $('.toggle2').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
    });
    $('#toggle3').click(function() {
    $('.toggle3').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
    });

    $('#toggle4').click(function() {
    $('.toggle4').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
    });
```

and here's the HTML...

```
 <div class="docBlocA">
  <div class="docTitle" id="toggle1">Document Title Goes Here (click to expand)</div>
  <div class="toggle1" style="display:none; width:100%;">Hidden div content here</div>
 </div><!--docBlocA-->

 <div class="docBlocB">
  <div class="docTitle" id="toggle2">Document Title Goes Here (click to expand)</div>
  <div class="toggle2" style="display:none; width:100%;">Hidden div content here</div>
 </div><!--docBlocB-->

 <div class="docBlocA">
  <div class="docTitle" id="toggle3">Document Title Goes Here (click to expand)</div>
  <div class="toggle3" style="display:none; width:100%;">Hidden div content here</div>
 </div><!--docBlocA-->

 <div class="docBlocB">
  <div class="docTitle" id="toggle4">Document Title Goes Here (click to expand)</div>
  <div class="toggle4" style="display:none; width:100%;">Hidden div content here</div>
 B</div><!--docBlocB-->
```

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use class selector and `next` method, `this` within the context of the handler refers to the clicked element.

```
$('div.docTitle').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

**Note**: DIV element doesn't have a default action, so you don't need `return false` unless you want to stop the propagation of the event.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 $('.docTitle').click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle('fast');
    });
```

Comment: @Amrendra.. You need to put quotes on `.doctitle` and class name also wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggle1,#toggle2,#toggle3,#toggle4').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Srinivas, but that opens all of the hidden div at once!